# Google Translate text-to-speech not working

Tags: google-play-store, text-to-speech

In Google Translate application, when I try to install text-to-speach, It gives me a box saying:

> Text-to-speach requires:
>   SVOX voice data: {disabled button}Installed{/disabled button}
>   Text-to-speach extended: {button}Click to install{/button}

On clicking, it goes to the market, where the search fails:

> There are no matches in the android market for the search:pname:com.google.tts

I use x10 mini, which had 1.6 earlier, so I thought like many other apps, this one requires higher versions. But now it's upgraded to 2.1 and still the same issue.

Has anyone else had this issue? Is this a bug in Translate? Is there a work-around?

Answer (score 1):

The app you are looking for is TTS Extended, search the market for it. I think the app stopped being available with version 2.2 because I can no longer find it on my phone, it is probably integrated now. Since you have 2.1 it should be there for you: [Here](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-google-tts-iDB.aspx) is a link to the app. I know it works because I used it on my previous droid in conjunction with Google translate, it worked very well with Italian by the way.

Comment: It didn't work for me unfortunately. Something wrong with google and the Indian market.